# Sum up input fields after some calulations

Tags: javascript

Hi I am writing a function to sum up the values of input areas, it should change the values dynamically. So when someone adds a new value the total value should automatically change.

Here is HTML-code:

```
<input id="fenster" onkeyup="val()" type="number">
<input id="fassade" onkeyup="val()" type="number">
<input id="keller" onkeyup="val()" type="number">
```

And here is the JS:

```
function id(id){return document.getElementById(id);}
var val1 = 0;
var val2 = 0;
var val3 = 0;
function val(){
val1 = parseInt(id("fenster").value);
val2 = parseInt(id("fassade").value);
val3 = parseInt(id("keller").value);
val_fenster = val1 * 30;
val_fassade = val2 * 30;
val_keller = val3 * 10;
id("total").innerHTML = ((val_fenster > 0 && val_fassade > 0 && val_keller > 0))?     val_fenster + val_fassade + val_keller: val_fenster;
}
```

The function only updates when all three values are included. But it would be good if it updates after every value and also if one does not enter the first value.

Comment: why id("total").innerHTML = val_fenster + val_fassade + val_keller; doesn't fit for you?

Comment: I get a NaN until I type all values. What would be nice, that it calculates the values also if not all values are entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The function only updates when all three values are included.

Presumably your `>0` checks are to handle the case where there are blank inputs because they will parse as `NaN` and anything `+ NaN == NaN`. So probably you best approach is to substitute `0` when your `parseInt` returns `NaN`. This can be easily done like this:

```
val1 = parseInt(id("fenster").value) || 0;
```

Now if `parseInt` gives `NaN`, which is falsy, you will assign `0` instead.

Also note, you should specify the radix for `parseInt`:

```
val1 = parseInt(id("fenster").value, 10) || 0;
```

Because leading zeros will cause it to think it's octal.

Also, it would probably be easier to assign a class to your inputs and then get them all at once and loop through them.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you can re-write the function as below, I have replaced the `onkeyup` method with `onblur` to fire the event only when the focus moves out of the input box and not on any keyup.

**HTML Code:**

```
<input id="fenster" onblur="val()" type="number">
<input id="fassade" onblur="val()" type="number">
<input id="keller" onblur="val()" type="number">

<div id="total"></div>
```

**JS Code:**

```
function id(id){
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
function val(){
    var val1 = parseInt(id("fenster").value) || 0,
        val2 = parseInt(id("fassade").value) || 0,
        val3 = parseInt(id("keller").value) || 0;

    console.log(val1, val2, val3);
    var val_fenster = val1 * 30,
        val_fassade = val2 * 30,
        val_keller = val3 * 10;

    id("total").innerHTML = val_fenster + val_fassade + val_keller;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function id(id){return document.getElementById(id);}
var val1 = 0;
var val2 = 0;
var val3 = 0;
function val(){
val1 = parseInt(id("fenster").value);
val2 = parseInt(id("fassade").value);
val3 = parseInt(id("keller").value);
if(!val1)
val1=0;
if(!val2)
val2=0;
if(!val3)
val3=0;
val_fenster = val1 * 30;
val_fassade = val2 * 30;
val_keller = val3 * 10;
id("total").innerHTML = ((val_fenster >= 0 && val_fassade >= 0 && val_keller >= 0))?            val_fenster + val_fassade + val_keller: val_fenster;
 }
```

It will work with out any problem

Comment: There is a condition if it is NaN then i am equating it to zero. i.e if(!val1) val1=0 , there by you will not get any NaN here

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this

```
id("total").innerHTML = (isNaN(val_fenster) && isNaN(val_fassade) && isNaN(val_keller))? (val_fenster + val_fassade + val_keller): val_fenster;
```